# How to tell what version of laravel from laravel full files?

Tags: laravel

I have a question to ask about laravel:  How to tell what version of laravel from the laravel full files?

I have a laravel files which I cannot tell what version is it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to project root directory and run `php artisan` command. The output will start from something like:

```
Laravel Framework version 5.3.30
```

5.3.30 is the version of Laravel used in this project.

Comment: which file to run in laravel framework in order to fun php artisan command?

Comment: @DavyYG `artisan` is PHP file in the root directory of a Laravel project. You need to just run `php artisan` is the console.

Comment: What software to use to run that file.  the extension of artisan is file.  I cannot run since it requires another software to run it.

Comment: When you run this command, you're running PHP. And PHP runs the script.

Comment: It asks me "Open with"  I do not know which software to pick?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Your project's root directory in command prompt and hit command like:

php artisan -V

> You will get your laravel version **Laravel Framework version 5.3.30**  like that

Answer (score 0):

If you can't or don't want to use artisan (`php artisan --version`), open `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php` you will find `const VERSION = '...';` defined in the class.